# How can I ignore certain files with extension except for folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file where I want to ignore all the bin folders and all the pdb files, except for the helper folder(bellow), in this helper folder I want to keep everything:

```
[Bb]in/
*.pdb

!project/helper/
```

All the pdb files and the bin folder are still excluded for the folder, I also tried:

- !project/helper/*
- !project/helper
- !project/helper/*.*

and even

- !project/helper/foo.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
*.php

!/web/sites/
!/web/sites/*.php
!/web/sites/default/
!/web/sites/default/*.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, we tried with this and it didn't work:

[Bb]in/

!project/helper/*/bin/*/
!project/helper/bin/*/*.pdb